# Quantifying the evenness-of-distribution of nodes within a necklace

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, necklace-and-bracelets

Given a necklace with n nodes that are distributed around a circle by a set of given deltas: How would you quantify how evenly the nodes are distributed.

(By "evenly" I mean that each node is maximally far from its neighbors)

For example in `Ex. 1` the set of deltas `{1,1,2,2,2,2,2}` can produce 3 necklaces with the following deltas:

```
1,1,2,2,2,2,2 (top of Ex. 1)
1,2,1,2,2,2,2
1,2,2,1,2,2,2 (bottom of Ex. 1)
```

How would you express that `1,1,2,2,2,2,2` is less evenly distributed than in 1,2,2,1,2,2,2 where the distances between the nodes is maximal?

What about a similar situation in Ex. 2?

**EDIT:**

A solution has been proposed below, which works for the majority of cases. But not for when there's an even number of all sizes.

The algorithm below, returns the same value for the following sets, even though they clearly have different levels of evenness of distribution:

`[1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2]` (as expected)

But also for:
`[1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2]`
`[1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2]`
`[1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2]`
`[1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2]`
`[1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2]`
`[1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2]`
`[1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2]`
`[1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2]`

[image]

Comment: Please edit the title.

Comment: Happy to. What's the issue you want me to fix? What about the title you find incorrect?

Comment: Made an edit, hope this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal is to measure the evenness of the distribution by comparing the actual positions of the nodes to the positions of equally many nodes that are perfectly evenly spaced.

For example, suppose that we have "deltas" of $1, 1, 2, 2$. Then the positions of the four nodes, normalized so that the first node has position $0$ and the length of the circle is $1$, are at $0, \frac16, \frac36, \frac56$. Four evenly spaced nodes would be at positions $0, \frac14, \frac12, \frac34$. So we have a sequence of four differences:
$$
   \left(0, \frac16, \frac36, \frac56\right) - \left(0, \frac14, \frac12, \frac34\right) = \left(0, -\frac1{12}, 0, \frac1{12}\right).
$$
In general, the signed average of these does not actually depend on the order of the "deltas". To see how big they tend to be, we could sum their absolute values, or (my choice) take the variance. As a bonus, it seems like the variance does not depend on the starting point (it gives the same result when we rotate the sequence of deltas).

The lower the variance, the more evenly the nodes are spaced.

For example, here are the permutations of `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]` sorted by this parameter:

[image]

Comment: This is interesting and promising, let me run some tests and see if I can come up with a case where it fails. Thank you very much!

Comment: This algorithm seems to be working correctly. Enjoy the bounty! Further thoughts if you have the time: Is there a theoretical maximal value? What does the maximum depend on? Also, how would you go about proving that this algorithm doesn't have edge cases where it fails? I mainly asking because I had used this algorithm already, and couldn't convince myself rigorously that it will always work.

Comment: Also, am I correct to assume that this same calculation can be used to quantify how similar are the different deltas between necklaces that have different constituents? That is, am I right that 12121212 would show less variance than 13131313, because while the distribution of the string (ABABABAB) is the same, the constituents in 12121212 (1s and 2s) are more self-similar than 1s and 3s?

Comment: Whether it will "work" or not is hard to say without a strict definition of what it means to "work". To prove the correctness of this algorithm, I'd want to formally state some desiderata, and show that it satisfies them. And - yes, we can compare certain necklaces with different deltas, but only if the number of nodes is the same; if the number of nodes is different, I don't think the comparison is meaningful.

Comment: you mentioned earlier that you prefer to express the variance over other properties. Can you explain why? Also would you mind helping me normalize the values? I'd like 1 to be maximally even (say [3,3,3,3]) and 0 to be minimally even (as if all of the necklace nodes occupy an infinitely close position on the necklace)

Comment: My preference for the variance is just intuition. To normalize the values, you could do the variance calculation for the sequences $[1,1,\dots,1,1]$ (maximally even) and $[0,0,\dots,0,1]$ (minimally even), both of the same length as the sequences you actually want to analyze. Then, apply some linear function that turns the first of these values into $1$ and the second into $0$.

Comment: I can across an outlier. both [3,4,3,4] and [3,3,4,4] output the same value, while intuitively the 1st is more evenly distributed the than latter. Any thoughts on how I can disambiguate such scenarios? Also, let me know if you'd like to appear in the acknowledgement section of the paper we're writing.

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich I get variance $\frac1{2352}$ for $[3,4,3,4]$ and $\frac1{1176}$ for $[3,3,4,4]$, which looks like it does what you want. Summing the absolute values of the deltas, however, does not distinguish the two. (I do not particularly seek to be acknowledged in the paper. I am generally in favor of StackExchange answers appearing as *citations* - click the Cite button below an answer for a citation format - but do not insist on that either.)

Comment: Thank you! I see that now!

Comment: The challenge that the variance measure is introducing is that it renders what we want to be a linear continuum into an exponential realm. Is there a way to linearize the variance? Would taking it sqrt suffice or does linearizing require a more sophisticated approach? The linear nature of the sum deltas was why we went that route previously.

Comment: The square root of variance (standard deviation) is linear in some ways - notably the units, when we're in a world with units - but not all ways. I'm not sure if it helps you here. Is your goal to get a measure between 0 and 1 where the values are not all clustered together around 0 or around 1? If so, that depends not just on how linear your formula looks, but on the space of necklaces and what values they actually give you. (The only foolproof method: replace the variance by a quantile function counting the fraction of less-even necklaces. Then you must measure all possible necklaces first.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! We can definitely do that! So to verify I'm understanding: If I get the variance of ALL necklaces in a space, I'd be able to basically "rank" the N necklaces 1 through N and than divide the rank by N to get a value between 0 and 1. That assume equidistant between the members. While we don't want an asymptote-like clustering near 0 or 1, we don't mind non-equidistant gaps between members if they are proportional to some extent of change. Do you believe the quantile route is the best to achieve our goals?

Comment: I think using quantiles is a decent fallback - but it would forget information about gaps, if it seems that there are any. I would actually begin by trying the variance calculation on a large space of necklaces and plotting it to see what kind of clustering you do or don't get. Switching to the standard deviation can reduce clustering near the "most evenly spread" end, but if you're not satisfied with either result, the quantile route is the only solution *I* can think of.

Comment: Here's the distribution: https://ibb.co/kcLgfwH 
I generated a largish space, and it's very clear that the values are very left shifted. I'd like to maintain the relative distances between the members, but also find a way to center the distribution.

Comment: No brilliant ideas come to mind. There's a small chance you could get somewhere by figuring out the distribution this data approximates. For example, if this were a Gaussian bell curve, it would be very clear how to compare the values (but of course it's not; it's always nonnegative).

Comment: Well, please keep me in mind if a brilliant idea comes to you. This is way beyond my pay grade! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_i$ be the set that locates $i$ in the set of nodes $S$.

$$ S = 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 \Rightarrow A_1 = \{1, 2\}, A_2=\{3,4\}, A_3=\{5,6\}$$
$$ S = 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 \Rightarrow A_1 = \{1, 4\}, A_2=\{2,5\}, A_3=\{3,6\}$$

Let $U_i$ be the sum of the distances between the elements of $A_i$ so that it would measure how evenly distributed the $A_i$'s are. ($n=|S|$)

$$ U_i = \sum_{a,b \in A_i} \min(|a-b|, n-|a-b|) $$

Let $U$ be the sum of the $U_i$'s so that it would represent how evenly distributed $S$ is.
$$ U = \sum U_i $$

Greater value of $U$ implies that $S$ is more evenly distributed.

Comment: This is so clever! Thank you very much! 
A couple of questions: 
1) I tried to apply this calculation to Ex. 1 and I wasn't sure if since I have many 1s, do I sum the differences only of neighbors or of every permutation? 

2) Does it make sense to compare the distribution between necklaces with completely different members? What if I asked which is more well distributed, the bottom of Ex.1 or the bottom of Ex. 2?

Comment: 1) Either would be fine as long as you apply the same for all sets, but it would be quicker and easier to take only the neighbors. In the equation, I meant the sum over all permutations because the notation for this is shorter.

Comment: 2) It depends on what your purpose of the quantification is. If it is purely mathematical, I think they should not be compared, but if it is for practical use, we can just assume that it makes sense. My equation tells that the bottom of Ex.1 is more evenly distributed, but if you don't think this suits your purpose, maybe try altering the equation a little.

Comment: Many thanks! Also, the equation can be normalized (between 0 and 1) if U is divided by |S|*|A|

Comment: we're writing a psychology paper for publication in a peer-reviewed journal and want to mention you in the acknowledgements. Send me a private message with your name and affiliation if you're interested.

Comment: Also, I just realized that {1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2} and {1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2} which probably shouldn't be the case.

Comment: are you still here?

Answer (score -2):

What you are talking about here is the [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)   of the string of deltas.

The complexity of a string is the length of the shortest possible description of the string in some fixed universal language.

What you call "more evenly" means higher Kolmogorov complexity.  What you call "less evenly" means lower Kolmogorov complexity.

This can be extended from binary strings to strings involving any finite number of distinct deltas.

Note added after comments discussion. Following the comments and correction,  you might need to consider the sequence of transitions of distinct deltas. Then what you call "more evenly " are the sequences that have corresponding sequences of transitions of distinct deltas of higher Kolmogorov complexity.

In your first example, wr write 0 for a 1 -->2 transition,  and 1 for a 2-->1 transition. Then the transition sequence of the first string is 10. The transition sequence of the second string is 010.

In your second example,  we write 0 for a 1-->2 transition,  1 for a 2-->1 transition,  2 for a 2 -->3 transition ,  3 for a 3-->2 transition,  4 for a 1-->3 transition,  and 5 for a 3-->1 transition.  Then in your second example,  your first string has transition sequence  02, and your second string has transition sequence 02502.

In both cases, what you call "more evenly " sequences are the sequences with transition sequences of higher Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134290/discussion-on-answer-by-cristian-dumitrescu-quantifying-the-evenness-of-distribu).